# mu4e-compose-dont-reply-to-self and address completion breaks on emacs exit

Tags: mu4e

My configuration seems correct, since I got it working for a week or so.
But after I quit `spacemacs` (using `SPC q q`), it stops working.

More details [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6teakg/help_mu4e_confusing_behaviour_address_suggestions/)

Is there any specific order required for `mu4e-compose-dont-reply-to-self` to work reliably all the time ? When it doesn't work, it is frustrating. So I would like fix that first.

Similarly, What configuration is required to see auto-completion for the addresses ? I haven't consciously configured anything. May be it "somehow" works. But I would like that to work always.

---

Edit dated Aug 17, 2017

It seems both these issues may be related to some "cleanup" not happening when `mu` or 'mu4e` exits (indirectly when emacs/spacemacs exits)

I noticed one more "bug" - my mu4e alerts were also "working", they have also stopped.

Comment: Auto complete addresses show up when you press TAB in the address field.